# Cannot borrow as mutable when running next on an immutable iterator (no other borrows)

Tags: rust

When trying to run the following code:

```
fn main() {
    let s1 = String::from("hello world");
    println!("The first word in the string is: {}", return_first_word(&s1));
}

fn return_first_word(s: &String) -> String {
    let t = s.split(" ");
    String::from(t.next().unwrap())
}
```

I get the error `cannot borrow as mutable` on the line `String::from(t.next().unwrap())`. Naturally, when I replace the line `let t = ...` with `let mut t = ...` the code works perfectly.

My question is, can someone explain why? What is being borrowed here, and by what? I checked the type of my newly created immutable variable `t` and it is an iterator. Why would it be an issue iterating over an iterator??

Comment: Do not post errors as images.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're familiar with a language like Java, you might expect `str::split` to return an array, but it actually doesn't. In Rust, [`str::split`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split) returns an iterator. It doesn't actually split the entire string immediately; it gives you a special iterator object that does it *as* you iterate over the string.

Now, iteration is a stateful process in Rust. To iterate over something, you call [`Iterator::next`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.next), which changes the iterator's internal state and produces the next value. If called repeatedly, it gives you every value of the iterator in order and then starts producing `None`. Since `next` changes the state of the iterator, it must have a mutable reference to the iterator.

When you declare a variable with `let` in Rust, it's immutable. You can't change it. You've told the Rust system you have no intention of changing it. So Rust complains when you try to take a mutable reference to a thing (in your case, an iterator) that you promised to never change. Instead, you need to use `let mut` to indicate your intentions.

Comment: Hey, I suspected this may be the case. It is just odd that I am able to create an immutable iterator at all, since those are practically useless as in I can't really iterate over them thus making it not an iterator! Thanks!

Comment: The mutability of a value can change when ownership changes hands. So, for instance, if you get an iterator, store it in a variable, and then pass ownership of it to some other function, even if the variable you stored it in was `let` (i.e. immutable), the function you gave it to can choose to mutate it. The iterator itself isn't immutable, just the variable that happened to own it at that moment.

Comment: Ah.. thanks. This makes so much sense!